# css animation-timing-function steps with different step timings

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a div where I'm animating the width from 0 to 100% in 3 steps. I'm using keyframes and an `animation-timing-function` of `steps(3)`.

I require the animation to be *non-linear* and stepped, such as having **the first two steps be faster, and the last step slower.**

```css
.animated {
  height: 10;
  width: 0;
  
  background-color: green;
  animation: extend;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(3);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes extend {
  0% { width: 0% }
  100% { width: 100% }
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100px">
  <div class="animated">x</div>
</div>
```

The above example will animate the width of the div between 0% and 100% in 3 *equal* steps. However, what if I want the animation to be non-linear? Is there a concise way to achieve this, preferably with css only?

##### What I have tried:

- I have tried using one step, specifying the section percentages in the keyframe, but the percentages seem to be off;
- I have tried using two separate divs with separate animations, but proved too difficult to implement cleanly;
- I have also tried specifying a non-linear mapping between animation progress and width in the keyframe, but produces unintended effects with incorrect increments, and overall an incorrect animation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for `cubic-bezier`

Comment: @tony Cubic bezier will produce a continuous function. Is there a way to 'step' a cubic bezier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `steps()` function is specifically designed to display each stop for the **same** amount of time.
To implement your task, try something like this (for demonstration, I increase a bit `animation-duration`):

```css
.animated {
  background-color: green;
  animation: extend 4s linear both;
}

@keyframes extend {
  0%, 19.999% { width: 0% }
  20%, 39.999% { width: 33.333% }
  40%, 99.999% { width: 66.666% }
  100% { width: 100% }
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100px">
  <div class="animated">x</div>
</div>
```